# Python cryptography module import error

Tags: python, module, pip, pyopenssl

I am attempting to run a website that is built on CherryPy and working on deploying it in a new environment with Python 2.7.13 and been working to get everything necessary setup. Currently I am stuck on importing pyOpenSSL to enable SSL support but pyOpenSSL is unable to install because a required module, Cryptography, is not installing. So I have been working on installing just Cryptography for the time being as all other required modules are installed.

Earlier, after I had used `pip2.7 install cryptography > /tmp/piplog.txt` to attempt to install the module and log the whole output to a separate file and I was able to see errors like these

```
gcc -pthread -fno-strict-aliasing -g -O2 -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -fPIC -I/usr/local/include/python2.7 -c build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/_openssl.c -o build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/_openssl.o
build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/_openssl.c:434:30: error: openssl/opensslv.h: No such file or directory
build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/_openssl.c:448:27: error: openssl/e_os2.h: No such file or directory
build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/_openssl.c:468:25: error: openssl/aes.h: No such file or directory
build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/_openssl.c:471:26: error: openssl/asn1.h: No such file or directory
```

This lead me to see where those files currently actually were installed with `find / -name opensslv.h` and then I copied the files from my install of openssl with

```
cp -rf /usr/local/ssl/inclue/openssl/* /usr/local/include/python2.7/openssl
```

so that the cryptography module would find the appropriate files and it seems like the installer got a bit farther, but I am not able to currently make sense of the errors I am seeing in the output. The full output is below

```
Collecting cryptography
  Using cached cryptography-1.9.tar.gz
Requirement already satisfied: idna>=2.1 in /usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages (from cryptography)
Requirement already satisfied: asn1crypto>=0.21.0 in /usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages (from cryptography)
Requirement already satisfied: six>=1.4.1 in /usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/six-1.10.0-py2.7.egg (from cryptography)
Requirement already satisfied: enum34 in /usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages (from cryptography)
Requirement already satisfied: ipaddress in /usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages (from cryptography)
Requirement already satisfied: cffi>=1.7 in /usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages (from cryptography)
Requirement already satisfied: pycparser in /usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages (from cffi>=1.7->cryptography)
Installing collected packages: cryptography
  Running setup.py install for cryptography: started
    Running setup.py install for cryptography: finished with status 'error'
    Complete output from command /usr/local/bin/python2.7 -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='/tmp/pip-build-VvLC6F/cryptography/setup.py';f=getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('\r\n', '\n');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, 'exec'))" install --record /tmp/pip-iAcBaS-record/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile:
    running install
    running build
    running build_py
    creating build
    creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7
    creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/cryptography
    copying src/cryptography/exceptions.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/cryptography
    copying src/cryptography/__init__.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/cryptography
    copying src/cryptography/utils.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/cryptography
    copying src/cryptography/__about__.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/cryptography
    copying src/cryptography/fernet.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/cryptography
    creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/cryptography/x509
    copying src/cryptography/x509/__init__.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/cryptography/x509
    copying src/cryptography/x509/extensions.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/cryptography/x509
    copying src/cryptography/x509/oid.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/cryptography/x509
    copying src/cryptography/x509/base.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/cryptography/x509
    copying src/cryptography/x509/general_name.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/cryptography/x509
    copying src/cryptography/x509/name.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/cryptography/x509
    copying src/cryptography/x509/certificate_transparency.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/cryptography/x509
    creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/cryptography/hazmat
    copying src/cryptography/hazmat/__init__.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/cryptography/hazmat
    creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/cryptography/hazmat/backends
    copying src/cryptography/hazmat/backends/interfaces.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/cryptography/hazmat/backends
    copying src/cryptography/hazmat/backends/__init__.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/cryptography/hazmat/backends
    creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/cryptography/hazmat/bindings
    copying src/cryptography/hazmat/bindings/__init__.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/cryptography/hazmat/bindings
    creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/cryptography/hazmat/primitives
    copying src/cryptography/hazmat/primitives/interfaces.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/cryptography/hazmat/primitives
    copying src/cryptography/hazmat/primitives/serialization.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/cryptography/hazmat/primitives
    copying src/cryptography/hazmat/primitives/padding.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/cryptography/hazmat/primitives
    copying src/cryptography/hazmat/primitives/mac.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/cryptography/hazmat/primitives
    copying src/cryptography/hazmat/primitives/cmac.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/cryptography/hazmat/primitives
    copying src/cryptography/hazmat/primitives/constant_time.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/cryptography/hazmat/primitives
    copying src/cryptography/hazmat/primitives/__init__.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/cryptography/hazmat/primitives
    copying src/cryptography/hazmat/primitives/hashes.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/cryptography/hazmat/primitives
    copying src/cryptography/hazmat/primitives/keywrap.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/cryptography/hazmat/primitives
    copying src/cryptography/hazmat/primitives/hmac.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/cryptography/hazmat/primitives
    creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/cryptography/hazmat/backends/openssl
    copying src/cryptography/hazmat/backends/openssl/rsa.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/cryptography/hazmat/backends/openssl
    copying src/cryptography/hazmat/backends/openssl/ciphers.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/cryptography/hazmat/backends/openssl
    copying src/cryptography/hazmat/backends/openssl/dh.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/cryptography/hazmat/backends/openssl
    copying src/cryptography/hazmat/backends/openssl/cmac.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/cryptography/hazmat/backends/openssl
    copying src/cryptography/hazmat/backends/openssl/dsa.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/cryptography/hazmat/backends/openssl
    copying src/cryptography/hazmat/backends/openssl/decode_asn1.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/cryptography/hazmat/backends/openssl
    copying src/cryptography/hazmat/backends/openssl/__init__.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/cryptography/hazmat/backends/openssl
    copying src/cryptography/hazmat/backends/openssl/ec.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/cryptography/hazmat/backends/openssl
    copying src/cryptography/hazmat/backends/openssl/x509.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/cryptography/hazmat/backends/openssl
    copying src/cryptography/hazmat/backends/openssl/backend.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/cryptography/hazmat/backends/openssl
    copying src/cryptography/hazmat/backends/openssl/utils.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/cryptography/hazmat/backends/openssl
    copying src/cryptography/hazmat/backends/openssl/hashes.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/cryptography/hazmat/backends/openssl
    copying src/cryptography/hazmat/backends/openssl/hmac.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/cryptography/hazmat/backends/openssl
    copying src/cryptography/hazmat/backends/openssl/encode_asn1.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/cryptography/hazmat/backends/openssl
    creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/cryptography/hazmat/bindings/openssl
    copying src/cryptography/hazmat/bindings/openssl/__init__.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/cryptography/hazmat/bindings/openssl
    copying src/cryptography/hazmat/bindings/openssl/binding.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/cryptography/hazmat/bindings/openssl
    copying src/cryptography/hazmat/bindings/openssl/_conditional.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/cryptography/hazmat/bindings/openssl
    creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/cryptography/hazmat/primitives/twofactor
    copying src/cryptography/hazmat/primitives/twofactor/totp.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/cryptography/hazmat/primitives/twofactor
    copying src/cryptography/hazmat/primitives/twofactor/__init__.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/cryptography/hazmat/primitives/twofactor
    copying src/cryptography/hazmat/primitives/twofactor/hotp.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/cryptography/hazmat/primitives/twofactor
    copying src/cryptography/hazmat/primitives/twofactor/utils.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/cryptography/hazmat/primitives/twofactor
    creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/cryptography/hazmat/primitives/asymmetric
    copying src/cryptography/hazmat/primitives/asymmetric/rsa.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/cryptography/hazmat/primitives/asymmetric
    copying src/cryptography/hazmat/primitives/asymmetric/dh.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/cryptography/hazmat/primitives/asymmetric
    copying src/cryptography/hazmat/primitives/asymmetric/padding.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/cryptography/hazmat/primitives/asymmetric
    copying src/cryptography/hazmat/primitives/asymmetric/dsa.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/cryptography/hazmat/primitives/asymmetric
    copying src/cryptography/hazmat/primitives/asymmetric/__init__.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/cryptography/hazmat/primitives/asymmetric
    copying src/cryptography/hazmat/primitives/asymmetric/ec.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/cryptography/hazmat/primitives/asymmetric
    copying src/cryptography/hazmat/primitives/asymmetric/utils.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/cryptography/hazmat/primitives/asymmetric
    creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/cryptography/hazmat/primitives/ciphers
    copying src/cryptography/hazmat/primitives/ciphers/algorithms.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/cryptography/hazmat/primitives/ciphers
    copying src/cryptography/hazmat/primitives/ciphers/__init__.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/cryptography/hazmat/primitives/ciphers
    copying src/cryptography/hazmat/primitives/ciphers/base.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/cryptography/hazmat/primitives/ciphers
    copying src/cryptography/hazmat/primitives/ciphers/modes.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/cryptography/hazmat/primitives/ciphers
    creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/cryptography/hazmat/primitives/kdf
    copying src/cryptography/hazmat/primitives/kdf/x963kdf.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/cryptography/hazmat/primitives/kdf
    copying src/cryptography/hazmat/primitives/kdf/kbkdf.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/cryptography/hazmat/primitives/kdf
    copying src/cryptography/hazmat/primitives/kdf/pbkdf2.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/cryptography/hazmat/primitives/kdf
    copying src/cryptography/hazmat/primitives/kdf/__init__.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/cryptography/hazmat/primitives/kdf
    copying src/cryptography/hazmat/primitives/kdf/concatkdf.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/cryptography/hazmat/primitives/kdf
    copying src/cryptography/hazmat/primitives/kdf/hkdf.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/cryptography/hazmat/primitives/kdf
    copying src/cryptography/hazmat/primitives/kdf/scrypt.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/cryptography/hazmat/primitives/kdf
    running egg_info
    writing requirements to src/cryptography.egg-info/requires.txt
    writing src/cryptography.egg-info/PKG-INFO
    writing top-level names to src/cryptography.egg-info/top_level.txt
    writing dependency_links to src/cryptography.egg-info/dependency_links.txt
    writing entry points to src/cryptography.egg-info/entry_points.txt
    warning: manifest_maker: standard file '-c' not found

    reading manifest file 'src/cryptography.egg-info/SOURCES.txt'
    reading manifest template 'MANIFEST.in'
    no previously-included directories found matching 'docs/_build'
    warning: no previously-included files matching '*' found under directory 'vectors'
    writing manifest file 'src/cryptography.egg-info/SOURCES.txt'
    running build_ext
    generating cffi module 'build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/_padding.c'
    creating build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7
    generating cffi module 'build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/_constant_time.c'
    generating cffi module 'build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/_openssl.c'
    building '_openssl' extension
    creating build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/build
    creating build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7
    gcc -pthread -fno-strict-aliasing -g -O2 -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -fPIC -I/usr/local/include/python2.7 -c build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/_openssl.c -o build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/_openssl.o
    build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/_openssl.c: In function ‘_setup_ssl_threads’:
    build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/_openssl.c:3400: warning: comparison is always false due to limited range of data type
    gcc -pthread -shared build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/_openssl.o -lssl -lcrypto -o build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/cryptography/hazmat/bindings/_openssl.so
    /usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lssl
    collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
    error: command 'gcc' failed with exit status 1

    ----------------------------------------
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, it seems that I was running into a similar error as before since once I added symbolic links to the libssl.so and libcrypto.so files to my /usr/lib/ directory. As root I did

```
ln -s /usr/local/ssl/lib/libssl.so /usr/lib/libssl.so
ln -s /usr/local/ssl/lib/libcrypto.so /usr/lib/libcrypto.so
```

After that I was able to successfully do `pip2.7 install cryptography` and `pip2.7 install pyOpenSSL`

Now when I start up my cherrypy website I no longer get errors about the pyOpenSSL being required.

Possibly some rookie mistakes with my previous software install caused the files to be not where the new installer was looking, or I should have known to put the symbolic link there to avoid these types of issues. But a good learning experience